# Where variables of a function is store? on stack or heap?

Tags: c#, .net, heap-memory, managed, stack-memory

When a program calls a function, in which type of data structure is memory allocated for the variables in that function? Heap or stack? why?

In my opinion it should store on stack because they are not necessarily reference types. But Where I read the answer, it is stated that they store on heap and free after function returns a value.

Comment: The answer is probably in the material you were assigned before this homework was given.

Comment: I am studying for MTA Certification and found it in preparation materials.

Comment: @Sama: Sounds like you need to find some better preparation materials, if they really say that.

Comment: I think she means the answer is ambiguous and unclear and needs help with it.

Comment: @kami The second part of the question is new with the edit. Originally the question was just `When a program calls a function, in which type of data structure is memory allocated for the variables in that function? Heap or stack? why?` After the edit showed some thought, the answers started rolling in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a little more complicated than that and the fact that the stack and heap are used are really implementation details. It makes more sense to talk about lifetime of data. Short lived data will be stored on the stack (or in registers). Long lived data is stored on the heap.

Instances of reference types are always considered long lived, so they go on the heap. Value types can be both. Local value types are typically stored on the stack, but if something extends the lifetime of such a variable beyond the scope of the function, storing it on the stack wouldn't make sense. This happens for captured variables and these will be stored on the heap even if they are value types.

Comment: I think that starts to bump up into language-specific features. I think in C# the value type parameters are copied. That's why changing the value of a value parameter inside the body of a function doesn't change the original (unless you specifically decorate it as pass by reference). So in that case, I believe a copy of the value is still pushed to the stack.

Comment: @ErikNoren Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to. The point is was trying to make is that a captured value types actually becomes a field of a compiler generated class, and is thus stored on the heap as part of the instance of said class.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are pushed to the stack before invoking a function. If the parameters are a value type, they can be stored directly. If they are a reference type, they are stored in the heap and a pointer to the memory location is pushed on the stack. When the function returns, the values are popped back off the stack and eventually the garbage collector will notice the memory on the heap no longer has a pointer to it and will clean it up too.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

And in Eric Lippert's own words:

> "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types
>   are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or
>   temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or
>   anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and
>   the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."

Comment: It seems to be more complex than what I thought.

Comment: I think it's taken to an absurd length in a humorous way. There's a difference between the basic concepts and compiler-specific, optimized implementations.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) If the variables in the function are of reference type, the references would be allocated on the stack but their associated objects will be on the heap. But if they are value type, the allocated memory will be on the stack. (I'm not 100% sure though).

For example, consider the following code.

```
public int myMethod(int x, int y, int z)
{
    double money;
    myClass myObjectRef = new myClass();
    return x + y + z;
}
```

In the above method, variables x,y,z and myObjectRef would be created on stack but the object that is made by "new myClass()" statement will be on the heap.

Comment: This isn't quite correct, if you look at how the question was worded. When a function is called, space is allocated on the stack. When a new object is constructed (if it's a reference type), *then* it is created on the heap.