# Mechanism of memory allocation to delegates in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, reference, delegates

We know that delegates are reference type which refers to function.

```
using System;
namespace Testing_Delegates

{

class Program
{
    delegate void fun_delegate();
    fun_delegate response;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        p.fun();//Calling function directly
        p.response += p.fun;//Setting reference to the function via delegate
    }

    public void fun()
    {
        int lvariable = 10000;
        string rvariable = "Hello Developers!";
        Console.WriteLine(lvariable + " " + rvariable);
    }
}
}
```

As we know local variables inside function (fun) are lvariable which is allocated memory on stack and rvariable contain reference to memory location of heap where the string is store.

Now,

> 1. When we define delegate or instance of delegate, where they (fun_delegate and response) allocate memory, whether on stack or on heap?
> 2. Why there is need to create an instance of delegate to reference it to any function?

Comment: may be you want to check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431902/where-variables-of-a-function-is-store-on-stack-or-heap

Answer (score 2):

> When we define delegate or instance of delegate, where they
>   (fun_delegate and response) allocate memory, whether on stack or on
>   heap?

`fun_delegate` in your example is a class and is stored in metadata.
`response` is a field in a reference type and is allocated on heap along with all the other fields of the said type.

> Why there is need to create an instance of delegate to reference it to
>   any function?

We need to create an instance to allocate place in memory to story the data. Unless you allocate memory for a field/variable, there is nowhere to store their value.